# Bootstrap 4 carousel slide not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, bootstrap-4

Hi all I am using Boostrap 4 beta-2 and am trying to get the carousel to use the slide animation. I had `class="item"` to the `"carousel-item"` class to get it to switch between slides (which also removed the `'offsetWidth undefined'` console error. However, the animation is still not working and just jumps between slides.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm not sure where the issue lies. (CSS/JS). There are no errors in the console.

```
<!--     *********     HEADER 3      *********      -->
<div class="header-3">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item carousel-item active">
                <div class="page-header header-filter">
                    <div class="page-header-image" style=""></div>
                    <div class="content-center">
                        <div class="container text-left">
                            <div class="content-center">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <div class="iframe-container">
                                            <iframe height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rmfmdKOLzVI?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto mr-auto text-right">
                                        <h1 class="title">On the run tour.</h1>
                                        <h4 class="description ">On the Run Tour: Beyoncé and Jay Z is a 2014 concert special which documents the September 12 and 13, 2014, shows of American singers' Beyoncé and Jay-Z joint co-headlining venture On the Run Tour.</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item carousel-item">
                <div class="page-header header-filter">
                    <div class="page-header-image" style=""></div>
                    <div class="content-center">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="content-center">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto text-center">
                                        <h1 class="title">Island of legends.</h1>
                                        <h4 class="description ">The islands of Malta and Gozo are brilliant for a family holiday, packed with fun places to visit whatever your children’s ages. The islands’ small size means everywhere is within easy reach.</h4>
                                        <br />
                                        <h5>Connect with us on:</h5>
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-icon btn-neutral btn-danger btn-round mt-2">
                                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-icon btn-neutral btn-danger btn-round mt-2">
                                                <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-icon btn-neutral btn-danger btn-round mt-2">
                                                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-icon btn-neutral btn-danger btn-round  mt-2">
                                                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item carousel-item">
                <div class="page-header header-filter">
                    <div class="page-header-image" style=""></div>
                    <div class="content-center">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="content-center">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                                        <h1 class="title">Arctic Sea ice.</h1>
                                        <h4 class="description ">According to the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration, Ted Scambos, NSIDC lead scientist, puts the potentially record low maximum sea ice extent this year down to low ice extent in the Pacific and a late drop in ice extent in the Barents Sea.</h4>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-neutral btn-primary btn-lg mr-1">
                                                <i class="now-ui-icons files_single-copy-04"></i> Read More..
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                                                <i class="now-ui-icons arrows-1_share-66"></i> Subscribe
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="now-ui-icons arrows-1_minimal-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <i class="now-ui-icons arrows-1_minimal-right"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--     *********    END HEADER 3      *********      -->
```

Comment: If I put the above snippet to a BS4 template it slides smoothly, so I guess other css interferes with bootstrap here.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="container" data-ride="carousel">
```

to this

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

[Carousel w/ Indicators documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators)

Comment: I already have that,  I do have that (just was trying to add it dynamically because someone suggested). Sorry I initially posted the wrong code

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have more then one .css file in your project. If you downloaded some themes from internet It could be that those styles rewrite original bootstrap classes and effected on your carousel.